# php referral system error

Tags: php, referrals

Ok, so im working on creating a referral system with a source code ive used from [Here](https://www.allwebtuts.com/msk-php-referral-system/)

Now ive installed everything but only changed my sql connect from `$con to $db`
So far whenever I create a URL, and try to access that link
I get a bad getway error: 
Ex: [image: Cr]
[image]

With my php code for the creation not including db connection just.

```
if(isset($_POST['create-ref']))
{

$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST["user"]);
$user=htmlentities($user);

//friendly URL conversion
function to_prety_url($str){
    if($str !== mb_convert_encoding( mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32') )
        $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($str));
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace('`&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig);`i', '\1', $str);
    $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $str = preg_replace(array('`[^a-z0-9]`i','`[-]+`'), '-', $str);
    $str = strtolower( trim($str, '-') );
    return $str;
}
$str=to_prety_url($user);

// sql query for inserting data into database
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO referral (user,str) VALUES ('$user','$str')";
$result_set=mysqli_query($db,$sql_query);

//Referral URL
$refurl="http://Mywebsite.com/refer/$str";  //replace it with your URL ex: http://example.com/refer/$str

}

?>
```

**UPDATE** NOTE THIS IS NOT THE SAME USER AS SHOWN IN THE EXAMPLE IMAGE ABOVE, THIS IS JUST TO SHOW IT SAVES IN MY DATABASE**
From there, it does save into my database like - [image]

Now for the form itself, the code looks like

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" data-parsley-validate>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="User Name" data-parsley-required="true" maxlength="25">
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" name="create-ref" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Create Now</button>
</div>
<br />

<?php
if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
echo "<div class='alert alert-success'><p class='inmt no-margin text-center'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Referral URL Created</p><br /><p><pre>$refurl</pre></p></div>";
}
?>

<br />
<a href="admin-panel.php" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">Go Back</a>

</form>
 </div>
 </div>
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
```

So is this a script error with my site not being able to validate the ref link, also i thought ref links were usually something like ?=ref, ?ref=, or something close to that.

Now checking the amount of clicks on the URL the script uses cookies.
And im getting an Instant 404 error whenever i try to access the form itsself. What seems to bee the problem with that?
[image]

with my php file for that being -

```
<?php
//status.php?id=USER_ID
include('db.php');

if($_GET['id'])
{

//variables
$id=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET["id"]);

//selecr from database
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM referral WHERE id='$id'";
$result_set=mysqli_query($db,$sql_query) or die('error');
$ref_row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set); //fetch the result from table
$count=$ref_row['clicks'];
$user=$ref_row['user'];

}

?>






<?php 
if($ref_row)
{
echo "<div class='col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-sm-8 center-block well login-form'><h2 class='par no-margin text-center'>Total Clicks</h2><p class='inmt no-margin text-center'>$user Refer $count Users</p></div></div>";
}
else
{
echo "<div class='col-md-6 col-lg-5 col-sm-8 center-block well login-form'><h2 class='par no-margin text-center'>OOps</h2><p class='inmt no-margin text-center'>404 Page boss</p></div></div>";
}
?>

**Took out unnecessary codes
```

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: `http:/` should be `http://`.

Comment: my mistake, i changed it for the sake of the post, but its like http:// in my actual form. Still the same error  though